# Как заменить значения в столбце на частоту их повторений во всех записях?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

у меня столбец `city` вида:

```
Denver
Denver
Denver
Chicago
New York
Chicago
Chicago
Denver
```

Как мне в этом же столбце заменить названия городов на количество их повторений.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
4
4
4
3
1
3
3
4
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
level_map = {(i, i) for i in df['city'].value_counts()}
df['city'] = df['city'].map(level_map)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Использовал это решение:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df['city'] = df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('size')
```

или так:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].map(df['city'].value_counts())
```